# RxSwift flatMap latest one time without disposing

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

Had a quick question: I have an `Variable<[Session]>`, where `Session`:

```
class Session {
  ...
  var rx_serverRequestable: Driver<SessionRequestable>
  ...
}
```

which emits a .next event every time the session has all the information it needs to be passed on to the backend  and I want to be able to `flatMapLatest` on the array of sessions, and do something like:

```
let sessions: Variable<[Session]>
sessions
    .flatMapLatest { sessions in sessions.map { $0. rx_serverRequestable } }
    .flatMap { $0.requestFromServer() }
```

but I only want to request each session once. There are two ways I see that failing with my current implementation:
1. flatMapLatest gets a new array of sessions, potentially disposing a request from server thats still in progress
2. rx_serverRequestable gets called each time the session has all the information required to be loaded from server, so it will get called multiple times, each time the session loads in any new information. I only  want the session to be requested the first time, should I be using something like `.multicast` or `.replay(1)`?

any pointers on solving the two issues, or switching up my approach?

Comment: What do you plan on doing with the result produced by the `sessions.flatMapLatest...flatMap` call?

Comment: Assign the information received from the server back into instance variables on the session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved using the `zip` operator http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html